# When are positive-sequence and negative-sequence equivalent impedance the same?

Tags: impedance, three-phase, fault, synchronous-motor

One of the topics we covered in an introduction to power systems class was using zero/positive/negative sequence networks to analyze faults in networks. For many problems, this requires setting up positive and negative sequence networks and their equivalent impedance.

My understanding is that balanced/static (?) components have equal positive/negative sequence impedance, while this can be different for generators (I think we're limiting ourselves to synchronous generators).

On to the real question: in one of the examples we are working out the fault current of a SLG fault, and a table is given with different negative/positive sequence impedance for the generator (as I would expect) but according to the solutions, the *equivalent* negative sequence impedance is the same as the equivalent *positive* sequence impedance (even though the generator impedance is used to calculate it).

So, what gives? Is this a special case for SLG faults, an approximation, or perhaps just a mistake?

(pretty much the entire faculty seems to be on vacation, and as a Physics major I don't know that many people that know this stuff... thanks in advance!)

Comment: the web search engines never go on holidays ... learn how to learn more efficiently. this is the goal of uni education with theory to practice your learning skills, https://cdn.selinc.com/assets/Literature/Publications/White%20Papers/LWP0010-02_TutorialSymmetrical-Pt2_AR_20140506.pdf?v=20170217-155658 try p10

Comment: Thank you for that document, which I have already found on my own searches... After all, that is why I have come to StackExchange. Specifically, the example in this document does exactly what I suspect should happen: different equivalent impedances because the generator has different impedance for neg. and pos. sequence.

That still does not answer my question whether there is something special about this - is it an acceptable approximation to ignore the difference for SLG faults, or otherwise specific to this type of fault?

Comment: I believe it depends proximity of network earth ground to ground fault impedance. If the problem is defined a solid ground or near trans. then ... yes